# Type error : list indices must be integers or slices, not st

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am using django restframework  to send a json like this :

```
[

{
  "email" : "niloofarharooni29@gmail.com",
  "email" : "admin22@admin.com",
   "meeting_date":"2021-06-29",
   "time_zone" : "Asia/Tehran"
}
]
```

and in views.py i need to get two fields like this:

```
serializer = EmailsListSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
meeting_date = serializer.data['meeting_date']
meeting_timezone = serializer.data['time_zone']
```

but i got this error and don't know how to solve it :

```
 TypeError at /user/prefertimes/

list indices must be integers or slices, not str
  /home/admin1/envs/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner

                    response = get_response(request)
```

Comment: Since this is a `many=True`, the seerialized data is a *list* that contains a dictionary, but *not* a dictionary, hence `serializer.data['time_zone']` does not make much sense.

Comment: `data` is a list, so you cannot index it with a string (such as `meeting_date`), but you have to use integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
serializer = EmailsListSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

Here you're providing `many=True`, which means that `serializer.data` is a **list** of dictionaries rather than a single dictionary. So, you need to access the the dictionary data like this:

```py
meeting_date = serializer.data[0]['meeting_date']
meeting_timezone = serializer.data[0]['time_zone']
```

Alternatively, if you're always sending just one dictionary in your list in the json, you can omit `many=True`

```py
serializer = EmailsListSerializer(data=request.data)
```

and send a dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries.

```json
{
    "email" : "niloofarharooni29@gmail.com",
    "email" : "admin22@admin.com",
    "meeting_date":"2021-06-29",
    "time_zone" : "Asia/Tehran"
}
```